# I get different size of images using Glide in Recycler View StaggeredGridLayout

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

I need to download image from web and I use `Glide` for this.

After downloading image they appears in Recycler Veiw. Part of images looks nice and fill all cell like this

[image]

But some images otherwise perform weird behavior and looks like this

[image]

As far as I understand such result due to Glade works asynchronous, and prior to moment when cell creating in adapter Glade don't have image and adapter creates default size for the cell... and only after a while glade came with image, but cell has already created with a wrong size.

But how to fix it?

I need adapter to wait until glade finish with downloading and than create cell for Recycler View

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/cvInbox"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
  app:cardElevation="15dp"
  >

<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/rippleInbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/standard_white"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/ntz_background_light_grey"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/cardMainActivityLinearLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/standard_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvBrandName"
          android:text="custom brand"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
          android:text="custom Type"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tvBrandName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
          android:text="custom price"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/bAction"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="button"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

          />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Glide in adapter**

```
ImageView iv = currentView.ivMainCard;
        String url = currentCard.getImageUrl();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .crossFade()
                .into(iv);
```

Comment: please share the code of the recycler item.xml file and the code of glide setting image in the view

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar sorry for typo . You are right

Comment: @IntelliJShivam added

Comment: add ScaleType: FitXY in the image tag attribute

Comment: @IntelliJShivam anyway doesn't work properly. But I found solution and published it bellow

Comment: Did anyone make it work with Glide yet? Would be glad if some can share light on what is happening because I the solution given below is for picasso and I am facing the problem with Glide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bindViewHolder of your recycler View you need to add to the imageView layout(0,0,0,0) with all zero parameters.In your case the code below

```
        ImageView iv = currentView.ivMainCard;
        iv.layout(0,0,0,0);

        String url = currentCard.getImageUrl();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .crossFade()
                .into(iv);
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case I just changed lib from `Glide` to `Picasso`

now my request looks like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .error(R.drawable.image_error_404)
                .into(iv);
```

and all is ok

Comment: @Aleskey did you also later find a way to make it work with Glide , cos I am facing the same issue

Comment: @user3701188, no eventually I am using Picasso. If is it possible, try to change Glade to Piccasso in your project that is it

Comment: I found a fix. You need to add to you imageview : "imageview.layout(0,0,0,0)"

Comment: @user3701188 really? And is it work? If so, please put as an answer, I will check it as right one